# Windows 10: Force logged on user to update its local group membership

Tags: windows, permissions, administrator

Is there a way to force a user to gain newly given local rights, without requiring the user to login again?

Assume the following scenario:

A computer is part of a Windows Domain environment. The user **DOMAIN\JOHN** logs on his computer, **JOHNPC**. The **DOMAIN\Domain Users** group is part of the local "**Users**" group on **JOHNPC**. So John is allowed to log onto the PC as a regular user.

If we then to remotely add **John** to the "Administrators" group of **JOHNPC**:

> **psexec \\JOHNPC net localgroup Administrators /add DOMAIN\JOHN**

This works. If the still logged on JOHN executes

> **net localgroup Administrators**

He will see himself as a local administrator. However, Windows does not reflect this. John is unable to run any elevated programs despite being a local admin. We notice he has to log off and log on again for Widnows to recognize his newly given local Administrator rights.

Is there a way to force this behaviour to update while John remains logged on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. When the user [logs on](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/windows-authentication/credentials-processes-in-windows-authentication#BKMK_CrentialInputForUserLogon), an [Access Token](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/access-tokens) is created (well, since UAC it’s technically two for elevated/non-elevated). The token is immutable. It contains an *immutable copy* of all privileges held by the token.

These tokens are usually inherited between processes, except with elevation.

The only way to get a new token is to log in again. You can also use `runas` for this purpose, even to restart `explorer.exe`. But any running processes will retain their old tokens.